# Fedex rate services issue (error code 999)

Tags: .net, fedex

I have developed a test Fedex rate services application using "`RateWebServiceClient.dll`", and it was working fine till 10th October 2013.

Now I am getting an issue, "`An unexpected exception occurred,code 999`" and `NotificationSeverityType.FAILURE="failure"`.

I did not do any modifications. I am also getting the same issue with the sample code downloaded from Fedex site. How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you [ask FedEx](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/get-support.html)?

Comment: yes an email support is requested but did n t get any reply @CodeCaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue and resolved it.

In the sample code, you need to use a valid destination address and return address.

I had the PHP sample code, so I'm guessing it might be the same thing in .NET. There are two functions that return the destination address and the return address, respectively, that had dummy addresses that needed to be replaced with real addresses.